# XHR http://localhost:8080/Jquery/data/produits.json/1 [HTTP/1.1 404 Introuvable 10ms]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise, ngresource

I can't fetch my element from my json file on localhost, how i can change *../produits.json/1* by *../produits/1* to solve my problem please ?

Here is my code :

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource']);

    myApp.factory('Produits',['$resource', function ($resource) {
        return $resource('data/produits.json/:id',{id: "@id"},
                 {
                    'update': {method: 'PUT'}

                 }
        );
    }]);

     myApp.controller('produitsCtrl', function($scope, $http,Produits,$log) {

         $scope.produits=Produits.query();


         $scope.product = Produits.get( {id: 1}  );    // GET
           scope.product.$promise.then(function(data) {
               $log.info(data);
           });
         $scope.set = function(){
             var u = Produits.save($scope.newProduct)
              $log.info(u);
             $scope.produits.push(u);
         }
 });
```

**HTML :**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" >

            <div ng-controller="produitsCtrl"> 

                <input  ng-model="newProduct" />{{newProduct}}<button ng-click="set()">update</button>
                {{product}}
            </div>

        </div>
```

**http://localhost:8080/Jquery/data/produits.json**

```
[
{
"id" : 1,
"reference": "AAAAAAAA",
"designation": "iphone 5C"
},
{
"id" : 2,
"reference": "BBBBBBBB",
"designation": "xxx"
},
{
"id" : 3,
"reference": "CCCCCCCC",
"designation": "nnnn"
}
]
```

Comment: you need to change your `$resource` url to ` $resource('data/produits/:id',{id: "@id"},
                 {
                    'update': {method: 'PUT'}

                 }`

Comment: thks, but that not solve the error :  http://localhost:8080/Jquery/data/produits/1   :[HTTP/1.1 404 Introuvable 10ms]

Comment: does `produits` method has implemented on server?

Comment: i have defined a $scope.produits like this : $scope.produits=Produits.query();

Comment: i asked you..do you have `produits` method on server side..

Comment: you should have create it on create on server side..

Comment: which server side platform you are using?

Comment: I asked you about Platform mann like .net, mongo, java, etc. on that code you need to add the `produits` OR you just wanted to filter josn?

Comment: then you need to add method in your `default.aspx.cs` that will send json to callee method..

Comment: can you show me example of this method please ?

Comment: you can't do this kind of thing with json file..if you want to create some feature like this then you need do some server side code

Comment: do you have a link for one example please ?

Comment: refer this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/791740/Using-AngularJs-ASP-NET-MVC-Web-API-and-EntityFram

Comment: one thing please : my _productSelected_ is a golobal variable, when i change product model that change, but with this method $scope.productSelected is fixed  : `Produits.query(function(data){ $scope.produits=data; $scope.reference=$scope.produits[$scope.productSelected].reference });`    I have to declare it locally, how can I do that dynamically